# Autohotkey script for releasing a key after being pressed in combination with another

Tags: autohotkey

Does anyone know what the script would be to release left after I press left **and** down?

I want it so that when I press and hold ← ↓, ← releases but ↓ continues to be pressed.

Answer (score 0):

```
~Left & Down::send, {Left Up}
```